# How to store an array of dictionary and display it on collection view in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift4

I am getting the data from json like an array of dictionary and I am extract using struct I made the struct like this:-

```
  struct Objects {
    var truckName : String!
    var truckCost : [String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()
```

And I am getting the data from son using alamofire

```
 Alamofire.request("my url", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else{ return}
            print("Response \(json)")
            guard let response = json["response"] as? [String:Any] else{ return}
            print(response)

            for (key, value) in response {
                print("\(key) -> \(value)")
                self.objectsArray.append(Objects(truckName: key, truckCost: value as! String))
               // self.objectsArray.append(Objects(truckName: key))

            }
            guard let msg = json["msg"] as? String else { return}
            print(msg)
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }

}
   Displaying data on collectioView
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "requestCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestCollectionViewCell
    cell.cellName.text = objectsArray[indexPath.item].truckName
    cell.moneyLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.item].truckCost
    cell.cell_Img.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    cell.cell_Img.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

If I am getting only truckName then everything is working and it is printing on collectionView but when I try to print truckCost It giving me this error :- ***Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x116bbe208) to 'NSArray' (0x116bbef28)***
[image]

Comment: truckCost is an Number

Comment: yes it a number

Comment: send json response you have

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish, Sir  I showed the postman json response above

Comment: where is truckCost

Comment: Sir when I am using truckCost it gives error you can see the commented  line I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast Int to [String]

Change [String] to Int in your Struct

```
struct Objects {
    var truckName : String!
    var truckCost : Int!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()
```

and in Alamofire function;

```
self.objectsArray.append(Objects(truckName: key as! String, truckCost: value as! Int))
```

Also where you declare cell;

```
if let unwrappedCost = objectsArray[indexPath.item].truckCost{ 
cell.moneyLabel.text = String(describing: unwrappedCost) 
}else{ 
cell.moneyLabel.text = "0" //Your Value If It can't Find Cost in Class 
}
```

Comment: let me try Sir.

Comment: Let me know If it is working. We'll look into If not.

Comment: I am getting a warning :- Cast from 'Int!' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Comment: Are you getting this warning on .append(Objects... line?

Comment: In my cell method

Comment: Can you please share your cell method?

Comment: cell.moneyLabel.text = (objectsArray[indexPath.item].truckCost as! String) here it is

Comment: You can't change string to Int with forcing it to String. try this "cell.moneyLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.item].truckCost"

Comment: We can continue in chat If you still have problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170528/discussion-between-viper-and-emre-onder).